# Transitions with nested data D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I've recently begun learning D3.js and I am struggling to create a transition in a scatter plot with the following data:

```
var data = [
    {"year" : "2004", "x":100, "y":300, "size": 2, "type": "A"},
    {"year" : "2005", "x":200, "y":200, "size": 2, "type": "A"},
    {"year" : "2006", "x":300, "y":100, "size": 2, "type": "A"},
    {"year" : "2004", "x":150, "y":250, "size": 2.382450, "type": "B"},
    {"year" : "2005", "x":150, "y":250, "size": 3.078548, "type": "B"},
    {"year" : "2006", "x":150, "y":250, "size": 4.265410, "type": "B"}];
```

Where in the scatter plot there are 2 points (type A&B) and they change location (x&y) and size by year. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0zz9m2y/) where I try to nest the data and plot the points, but making the next step of using transition() function is confusing. More specifically, I am still declaring the whole data, but to make transitions work I only need part of the data.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you need, but I think you would need to nest by type, and create circle per type. but you need something to trigger the transition (user click, timer?) to iterate through the data.values for each year.

Comment: eg https://jsfiddle.net/whx0e4f1/

Comment: How is the transition supposed to work, if both types of circles are on the screen at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understand what you want lies here:

> There are 2 points and they change location (x&y) and size by year

Therefore, this is clearly a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your problem is not *"how to transition with nested data"*. Your problem is *"how to transition by year"*.

My proposed solution involves, first of all, dropping that nested array. You don't need that.

Instead, get all the years in the data...

```
var years = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.year
}))];
```

..., filter the data by year...

```
var dataStart = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.year === years[0]
});
```

... and loop trough the years. Here, I'm using `d3.interval()`:

```
var counter = 1;
var timer = d3.interval(transition, 1500);

function transition() {

  var newData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.year === years[counter]
  });

  svg.selectAll("circle").data(newData)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      console.log(d)
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.size * 10;
    });
  counter += 1;
  if (counter === 3) {
    timer.stop()
  }
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
      "year": "2004",
      "x": 100,
      "y": 100,
      "size": 2,
      "type": "A"
    }, {
      "year": "2005",
      "x": 200,
      "y": 180,
      "size": 2,
      "type": "A"
    }, {
      "year": "2006",
      "x": 300,
      "y": 50,
      "size": 2,
      "type": "A"
    }, {
      "year": "2004",
      "x": 150,
      "y": 150,
      "size": 2.382450,
      "type": "B"
    }, {
      "year": "2005",
      "x": 150,
      "y": 50,
      "size": 3.078548,
      "type": "B"
    }, {
      "year": "2006",
      "x": 150,
      "y": 100,
      "size": 4.265410,
      "type": "B"
    }];

    var width = 400,
      height = 200;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var years = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.year
    }))];

    var dataStart = data.filter(function(d) {
      return d.year === years[0]
    });

    var cell = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataStart);

    cell.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.size * 10;
      });

    var counter = 1;
    var timer = d3.interval(transition, 1500);

    function transition() {

      var newData = data.filter(function(d) {
        return d.year === years[counter]
      });

      svg.selectAll("circle").data(newData)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        })
        .attr("r", function(d) {
          return d.size * 10;
        });
      counter += 1;
      if (counter === 3) {
        timer.stop()
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does achieve what I was hoping for. I was trying to avoid loops since I was reading that you could avoid them with D3.js using nests, but I guess loops are fine here

Comment: Indeed, you should always avoid loops in D3 when appending elements. But here you're talking about changing the data, which is different.